# Submit data via AJAX in .NET embedded browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, ajax

We have a setup where a .NET embedded browser is used to display an HTML page generated by applying an XSLT file to an XML file (using .NET). This generates HTML that is displayed in the embedded browser using the `DocumentText` property.

What I want to achieve is send some data to the .NET component using AJAX on `onmouseover`. The problem is, the .NET app states that the URL is `about:blank` and that's also what the manual says about using the `DocumentText` property:

> Use this property when you want to manipulate the contents of an HTML
>   page displayed in the WebBrowser control using string processing
>   tools. You can use this property, for example, to load pages from a
>   database or to analyze pages using regular expressions. When you set
>   this property, the WebBrowser control automatically navigates to the
>   about:blank URL before loading the specified text. This means that the
>   Navigating, Navigated, and DocumentCompleted events occur when you set
>   this property, and the value of the Url property is no longer
>   meaningful.

So how can I use AJAX inside this component? I have no URL to submit to...

Has anyone achieved this? Btw, I only do the JS, I don't code the .NET.

My code that doesn't work:

```
    <script>

    function fnLog(action,rule){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
//or: url:'about:blank',
//or: url: '',
//or url: 'localhost',
          data: "xmlToPost=<cr>"+
    " <guiActions>"+
        " <log>"+
           "  <action>"+action+"</action>"+
           "  <ruleId>"+rule+"</ruleId>"+
         "</log>"+
    " </guiActions>"+
 "</cr>"
        });
    }

    </script>
```

Edit:
I know about `window.external.Post`, but that would only work in IE and would be different from the rest of the code. The .NET developer would like to stick to one way of sending data to .NET, which at this point is done by posting it, only posting a form on every `mouseover` is not great, so that's why I'm looking at `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to navigate somewhere else, for example `ajax://<cr><guiAction.....` and the .NET component will be notified about this, take the new URL and parse it accordingly and prevent the redirection so nothing will actually happen with the page.